# jsonb_agg with CASE Condition

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

hello i have issue with using case on json_agg, i want to return empty list on return_items field if left join is false, but when i tried this

```
select 
so.id as so_id,
so.name as so_number,
rp.name as mitra_name,
json_build_object(
    'id', rc.id,
    'name', rc.name
) as store,
CASE WHEN sp.delivery_type = 'direct' THEN true ELSE false END as is_direct,
CASE WHEN sp.origin ilike 'Return%%' THEN true ELSE false END as is_from_return_doc,
sp.id as picking_id,
CASE WHEN sp.origin ilike 'Return%%' THEN
    jsonb_agg(
        json_build_object(
            'id', sm.id,
            'product_id', pp.id,
            'available_uom_items', apu.items
       )
    ) 
ELSE
   # should be empty list [] or empty dict {}
END as return_items
from sale_order so
JOIN res_partner rp on
    so.partner_id = rp.id
JOIN res_company rc on
    so.company_id = rc.id
LEFT JOIN stock_picking sp ON
    sp.sale_id = so.id and sp.origin ilike 'Return%%' and sp.state not in ('cancel', 'done')
LEFT JOIN stock_move sm on
    sm.picking_id = sp.id
LEFT JOIN product_product pp on
    sm.product_id = pp.id
LEFT JOIN product_template pt on
    pp.product_tmpl_id = pt.id
LEFT JOIN product_uom sm_uom ON
    sm.product_uom = sm_uom.id
LEFT JOIN product_identity_uom piu ON
    piu.product_id = pt.id 
    AND piu.uom_id = sm.product_uom
LEFT JOIN available_product_uom apu ON
    apu.product_id = pt.id
LEFT JOIN ir_attachment ir ON
    ir.res_id = pt.id
    and ir.res_model = 'product.template'
    and ir.res_field = 'image'
```

and i got this error message

CASE types boolean and jsonb cannot be matched
LINE 44:                         jsonb_agg(

can someone help me? or is there any way than use jsonb_agg? thanks

Comment: Where's the rest of your SQL?

Comment: `"empty list"` is an identifer. Do you have a column with that name?

Comment: The alias as return_items should be outside of the CASE statement

Comment: i just updated my full query sir @FrankHeikens

Answer (score 0):

i've found the answer

```
CASE WHEN sp.id IS NULL THEN
    json_build_object()
ELSE
    json_agg(
        json_build_object(
            'id', sm.id,
            'product_id', pp.id,
            'product_sku', pt.default_code,
            'product_name', pt.name,
            'image_url', CASE WHEN ir.store_fname IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT(%(aws_image_url)s, ir.store_fname) ELSE '' END,
            'quantity', sm.product_uom_qty,
            'uom', json_build_object(
                'id', sm_uom.id,
                'name', sm_uom.name,
                'factor', sm_uom.factor,
                'barcode', piu.barcode
            ),
            'available_uom_items', apu.items
        )
    ) 
END as return_items,
```